# The stylesheet style.css was not loaded because its MIME type, “text/plain”, is not “text/css”

Tags: css, django

I have a django website on my local and it was ok last week , i can not remember if i changed anything in its codes but today i faced some errors and css files are not working 
this is its error on  browser developer tools:

```
The stylesheet http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/style.css was not loaded because its MIME type, “text/plain”, is not “text/css”.
```

and also same errors on aother pages related to css

```
The stylesheet http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/autocomplete_light/select2.css was not loaded because its MIME type, “text/plain”, is not “text/css”
```

these are my html codes on the base page which other pages extends

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" >
<title> </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap-rtl.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/jquery-ui.css' %}">

</head>

<body >
 ....
 ....
</body>
```

Comment: show your html where the css are added

Comment: Is this anything related to windows ? or related to my codes ?

Comment: this problem happens becouse i installed a program (nusphere). i uninstalled this program but still the problem exists

Comment: the site appearance is ok in oera browser but it has problem in chrome, mozillafirefox and internet explorer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm on Windows 7 and This is how I fixed it:

1-On your computer search for "regedit.exe" (go to the start menu and click on the search button on the top-right corner of the screen).

2-Once regedit opens up, on the left column click on "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT" and then on ".css"

3-On the right column double-click on "Content Type". This will open up a dialog box.
    In the dialog box change "value data" to "text/css".

4-Click "Ok" and that's it.

I hope this helps other people out there.